# How to make the dwarf sections get loaded into memory in an elf file?

Tags: c, linker, elf, dwarf

I am writing a C program without the standard library, which is loaded into memory by an elf loader and then executes. I wish for this C program to also be able to have its dwarf debugging sections loaded into memory so it can print a backtrace at runtime.

To try to achieve this, I've placed in my C program:

```
extern char __my_old_debug_abbrev_start[];
extern char __my_old_debug_abbrev_end[];
extern char __my_old_debug_info_start[];
extern char __my_old_debug_info_end[];
extern char __my_old_debug_str_start[];
extern char __my_old_debug_str_end[];
```

So it can figure out where the sections are. Then to actually provide the locations, I have a linker script which looks like:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .debug_abbrev : {
    __my_old_debug_abbrev_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.debug_abbrev)) *(.debug_abbrev)
    __my_old_debug_abbrev_end = .;
  }
  .debug_info : {
    __my_old_debug_info_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)) *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
    __my_old_debug_info_end = .;
  }
  .debug_str : {
    __my_old_debug_str_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.debug_str)) *(.debug_str)
    __my_old_debug_str_end = .;
  }
}
INSERT AFTER .rodata;
```

First, I compile the C program into a `libtest.a` and then use `objcopy` to set the sections to be `alloc` and `load`.

```
objcopy --set-section-flags '.debug_abbrev=alloc,load' libtest.a
objcopy --set-section-flags '.debug_info=alloc,load' libtest.a
objcopy --set-section-flags '.debug_str=alloc,load' libtest.a
objcopy --set-section-flags '.gnu.linkonce.wi.*=alloc,load' libtest.a
```

Then, I run gcc on the archive to compile it into an executable, along the lines of:

```
gcc libtest.a -o test -T test.lds -static
```

This produces errors:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: section .debug_info LMA [0000000000000000,0000000000066291] overlaps section .debug_abbrev LMA [0000000000000000,0000000000007cce]
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: section .debug_str LMA [0000000000000000,000000000009d264] overlaps section .debug_info LMA [0000000000000000,0000000000066291]
```

I'm not sure how to fix this as the sections only really exist after linking(?) and then maybe I can adjust the lma with `objcopy`(?) but then I'm not sure where I would place them.

I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/31126336/3492895 but I am not sure how I would create the "hole" before linking so I can use `objcopy` to adjust things.

Comment: try to merge the three output sections into one, call it something like `.debug_all`, then post the result

Answer (score 1):

Using user2162550's suggestion, the code managed to compile but some code I had to print out the function names which were in the debugging information were printing out nothing. I then saw a comment in the default linker script gcc uses (by passing `-Wl,--verbose` to it when linking the executable):

```
/* DWARF debug sections.
  Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
  of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
...
.debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
.debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
...
```

This convinced me that it didn't matter where the debugging symbols were, in the final binary. So then I tried to use the hole trick (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31126336/3492895)) but I wasn't sure how to copy the debugging info before the executable was linked (once the executable is linked, I don't think `objcopy` works anymore). So I decided to leave some space which is loaded and allocated in the binary and then, after linking, copy the required sections into that space.

To do this, I used the linker script to leave a hole and to also provide symbols to figure out where the debugging sections are. The method I got working was to use the linker script to first measure the size of each debugging section and then allocate enough space for it. This looks like (in `test.lds`:

```
/* This finds the start and end of each section so we know its size */
SECTIONS
{
  .debug_info 0 : {
    __my_old_debug_info_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)) *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*)
    __my_old_debug_info_end = .;
  }
  .debug_abbrev 0 : {
    __my_old_debug_abbrev_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.debug_abbrev)) *(.debug_abbrev)
    __my_old_debug_abbrev_end = .;
  }
  .debug_str 0 : {
    __my_old_debug_str_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.debug_str)) *(.debug_str)
    __my_old_debug_str_end = .;
  }
}
INSERT AFTER .rodata;

/* This creates some space in the binary which is loaded and big enough to store all the debugging info, as well as marking the start and end of each area */
SECTIONS
{
  .debug_all : {
    __my_debug_info_start = .;
    . += __my_old_debug_info_end - __my_old_debug_info_start;
    __my_debug_info_end = .;
    __my_debug_abbrev_start = .;
    . += __my_old_debug_abbrev_end - __my_old_debug_abbrev_start;
    __my_debug_abbrev_end = .;
    __my_debug_str_start = .;
    . += __my_old_debug_str_end - __my_old_debug_str_start;
    __my_debug_str_end = .;
  }
}
INSERT AFTER .rodata;
```

I think the choice of `.rodata` for `INSERT AFTER` is arbitrary.

Then, I compiled and linked with:

```
gcc libtest.a -g -o test -T test.lds -static
```

Taking inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26776602/3492895), I had a bash script parse the output of `readelf` and compute where in the binary to get the debugging information from and where to copy it to so it would get loaded. The copying is done using `dd`.

```
function getSymbolValue {
  binary=$1
  symbol=$2

  # Assumes that this will only find one symbol
  truncated_symbol=`echo $symbol | cut -c 1-25`
  readelf -s $binary | grep $truncated_symbol | awk '{print $2}'
}
function getSectionInfo {
  binary=$1
  section=$2

  # returns all but the [Nr] column of data returned by readelf
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795522/3492895
  readelf -S $binary | cut -c7- | grep '\.'"$section"
}
function getSectionAddress {
  binary=$1
  section=$2

  getSectionInfo $binary $section | awk '{print $3}'
}
function getSectionOffset {
  binary=$1
  section=$2

  getSectionInfo $binary $section | awk '{print $4}'
}
function copyData {
  binary=$1
  from_start=$2
  to_start=$3
  len=$4

  dd iflag=skip_bytes,count_bytes if=$binary skip=$from_start count=$len | dd oflag=seek_bytes of=$binary seek=$to_start count=$len conv=notrunc
}
function copyDebugSection {
  binary=$1
  from_section=$2
  to_section=$3

  from_off=`getSectionOffset $binary $from_section`
  to_section_off=`getSectionOffset $binary $to_section`
  to_section_addr=`getSectionAddress $binary $to_section`
  to_start_addr=`getSymbolValue $binary "__my_${from_section}_start"`
  to_end_addr=`getSymbolValue $binary "__my_${from_section}_end"`

  copyData $binary $((0x$from_off)) $((0x$to_start_addr - 0x$to_section_addr + 0x$to_section_off)) $((0x$to_end_addr - 0x$to_start_addr))
}

copyDebugSection ./test 'debug_info' 'debug_all'
copyDebugSection ./test 'debug_abbrev' 'debug_all'
copyDebugSection ./test 'debug_str' 'debug_all'
```

After running this, the functions names I were expecting, were printed out.

If anyone was wondering how I printed out the function names, I wrote some code in rust using the library gimli. Since this was irrelevant to the question I didn't include it. I used this to ensure that the correct debugging information was there, since I didn't find any magic dwarf numbers to look for online to ensure integrity of the information.

The only potential problem is that when running `readelf`, it outputs:

```
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
   Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
...
readelf: Warning: [ 3]: Link field (0) should index a symtab section.
  [ 3] .rela.plt         RELA             0000000000400168  00000168
   0000000000000228  0000000000000018  AI       0    25     8
```

But I do not understand what this means and it does not *seem* to pose a problem.

Please tell me if there is anything I can do to improve this question or answer.

Comment: You could be able to get the start and end of your debug sections by declaring (and taking the addresses of) something like `extern void __start_debug_info, __stop_debug_info;` to avoid the symbol placement shenanigans. See this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16552710/how-do-you-get-the-start-and-end-addresses-of-a-custom-elf-section-in-c-gcc

Comment: @zneak I tried that, replacing `. += __my_old_debug_info_end - __my_old_debug_info_start;` with `. += __stop_debug_info - __start_debug_info;` and etc. in the linker script and removing the first `SECTIONS` block . The linker spit out: ` undefined symbol `__stop_debug_info' referenced in expression`, so it didn't seem to have worked. D=

Comment: What if you use them from your C code instead of integrating them to the linker script? Is the problem then that your sections aren’t copied to the executable?

Comment: I think the problem would then become figuring out how big the custom `.debug_all` section should be to contain a copy of the debug sections. I tried using `SIZEOF` but that doesn't seem to work. It seems to return 0 if `.debug_all` is `INSERT AFTER .rodata` but if we insert it later, after the last debug section, it returns a non-zero value. But then `readelf` reports `Warning: DIE at offset 0xb refers to abbreviation number 1 which does not exist` and the debug sections do not seem to parse properly.